# The method add(Figura2D) in the type Set<Figura2D> is not applicable for the arguments (Rettangolo)

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Hi I don't know how to solve my problem at line where is HERE!!!
It's said:
The method add(Figura2D) in the type Set is not applicable for the arguments (Rettangolo)
I try to do this:

```
 package packAppello170919;
public class Figura2D {
    private Object obj;

    public Figura2D(){}
    public Figura2D(Object figura){
        if(figura instanceof Rettangolo){
            obj= (Rettangolo)figura;
        }//I do the same thing with another type of object(Cerchio)
    }}}
```

Figura2D must contain Cerchio and Rettangolo, but I don't know how to do this, I can obviously modify at the main, but I can't do that because this is the test of the exercises
I put the a piece of the code thus you can do tested.
Thank you

```
public static Set<Figura2D> generaSetFigure() {
            Set<Figura2D> F = new HashSet<Figura2D>();

            Punto p1 = new Punto(1,1);
            Punto p2 = new Punto(2,2);
            Punto p3 = new Punto(3,3);

            Rettangolo r1 = new Rettangolo(p1,p2);
            Rettangolo r2 = new Rettangolo(p1,p3);
            Rettangolo r3 = new Rettangolo(p2,p3);

            Cerchio c1 = new Cerchio(p1,1.0);
            Cerchio c2 = new Cerchio(p1,2.0);
            Cerchio c3 = new Cerchio(p3,1.0);

            F.add(r1); F.add(r2); F.add(r3);  //HERE!!!!
            F.add(c1); F.add(c2); F.add(c3);

            return F;
        }
```

Comment: Suggested reading: [Oracle's Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html) on classes.

Comment: the line of code where error happens could be rewritten in following way: `F.add(new Figura2D(r1)); F.add(new Figura2D(r2)); F.add(new Figura2D(r3));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Rettangolo` is not an instance of `Figura2D`.
In `Rettangolo` class add `extends Figura2D` to use inheritance.

```
public class Rettangolo extends Figura2D{}
```

Comment: I think you're right, I must extends Cerchio to Figura2D too, right? Because Rettangolo and Cerchio must be a figura2D. I'm going to write from the start the code tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: Yes, Punto and Cerchio you should do exact the same way.
Here's more on inheritance: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html .
Once you do it, remove "private Object obj;" from Figura2D class, and the second constructor (the one with an argument) since you don't need it anymore.
If that solves your problem, please approve this answer. Good luck :)